# Draggable function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: **Update 1**]I am working on a website where I have to implement post-it notes features. Right now I've two different types of post-it notes, one which allows a picture to be uploaded and the other allows text to be added. My picture one post-it note is draggable however my text one is not. I have looked at everything but I can't seem to find the cause. I did some research before posting here so I am sure I'm not posting the same question. **The silver plus button is for the editable post-it notes and the blue is for the picture one.**

Here is my link to the code:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdzgwwvd/)

My problem seems to be with this code (line 28 on JSFiddle).

```
<div id="react-container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    var Note = React.createClass({
        getInitialState() {
            return {editing: false}
        },
        componentWillMount() {
            this.style = {
                right: this.randomBetween(0, window.innerWidth -150, 'px'),
                top: this.randomBetween(0, window.innerHeight -150, 'px')
            }
        },
        componentDidUpdate() {
            if (this.state.editing) {
                this.refs.newText.focus()
                this.refs.newText.select()
            }
        },
        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
            return this.props.children !== nextProps.children || this.state !== nextState
        },
        randomBetween(x, y, s) {
            return (x + Math.ceil(Math.random() * (y-x))) + s
        },
        edit() {
            this.setState({editing: true})
        },
        save() {
           this.props.onChange(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.id)
           this.setState({editing: false})
        },
        remove() {
            this.props.onRemove(this.props.id)
        },
        renderForm() {
            return (
                <div className="note" style={this.style}>
                    <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
                    <button onClick={this.save}>SAVE</button>
                </div>
            )
        },
        renderDisplay() {
            return (
                <div className="note" style={this.style}>
                    <p>{this.props.children}</p>
                    <span>
                        <button onClick={this.edit}>EDIT</button>
                        <button onClick={this.remove}>X</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
               )
        },
        render() {
            return ( <ReactDraggable>
            {(this.state.editing) ? this.renderForm() : this.renderDisplay()}
            </ReactDraggable>
            )
        }
    })

    var Board = React.createClass({
        propTypes: {
            count: function(props, propName) {
                if(typeof props[propName] !== "number") {
                    return new Error("the count must be a number")
                } 

                if(props[propName] > 100) {
                    return new Error("Creating " + props[propName] + " notes is ridiculous you need to delete some to make more.")
                }   
            }
        },
        getInitialState() {
            return {
                notes : []
            }
        },

        nextId() {
            this.uniqueId = this.uniqueId || 0
            return this.uniqueId++
        },
        add(text) {
            var notes = [
                ...this.state.notes,
                {
                    id: this.nextId(),
                    note: text
                }
            ]                
            this.setState({notes})
        },
        update(newText, id) {
            var notes = this.state.notes.map(
                note => (note.id !== id) ?
                    note :
                    {
                        ...note,
                        note: newText
                    }
                )
            this.setState({notes})
        },
        remove(id) {
            var notes = this.state.notes.filter(note => note.id !== id)
            this.setState({notes})
        },
        eachNote(note) {
            return (<Note key={note.id} id={note.id} onChange={this.update} onRemove={this.remove}>{note.note}</Note>)
        },
        render() {
            return (<div className='board'>
                        {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
                        <button onClick={() => this.add('New Note')}>+</button>
                    </div>)
        }
    })

    ReactDOM.render(<Board count={10}/>,
        document.getElementById('react-container'))

</script>
```

I know it is tough to look at someone's else code but if possible, can anyone please point me in the right direction? Right now, I tried everything but my editable post-it notes are not draggable so far.

Comment: When I create a text note, I see this error in the console: `Uncaught Error: getNodeFromInstance: Invalid argument`. That error has been reported in [this issue](https://github.com/furqanZafar/react-selectize/issues/96).

Comment: I just added an image. It's weird I don't get any error message. You can take a look at the image. @ConnorsFan

Comment: I see the error in the browser console in Chrome, when I add a text note.

Comment: And I also see the error in the browser console in Firefox.

Comment: I am currently using macOS and I checked it with Chrome and Safari, both seem okay. It's weird now. @ConnorsFan

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make your element draggable:

```
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById(("mydiv")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

Make sure you connect the JavaScript correctly in your CSS and HTML.

Comment: I've looked at that website. But that one doesn't seem to work with mine.

Comment: There are no errors but the problem is when I try to use that code, it just doesn't work at all. Right now, I can edit a post-it note but with that code, everything disappears and I get a blank screen.

Comment: So the code I posted above fails without any errors in the console. Have you tried it with more than one browser? Have you also perhaps tried it in a virtual machine with another operating system on it?

Comment: Yes! Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: Have you tested it with another virtual machine, or on another computer? Are you in development or production?

Comment: Windows and macOS so far. But I am sure it is not because of that but I feel like there is a clash between the two post-it notes code and that's causing the editable post-it note to be not draggable.

Comment: Can you accept the move to chat? I can't at the moment because of my current reputation level.

Comment: How should I do that? I do not see any chat option here. :(

Comment: When you make a comment it should come up with a message saying 'Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?'. automatically move this discussion to chat should be a link.

Comment: It does not ask me for that. I have used the chat before but for some reason, I don't see the chat pop up here. I think for that to pop up, the conversation should have a min of 15 messages back and forth altho I am not sure.

Comment: You said you think there's a 'clash'. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I just removed the code for the picture post-it note and just left the code for the editable one and it still seems to be not draggable. So, I was wrong in saying that they clash. the problem seems to be with the editable post-it note code.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle at all?

Comment: The link is at the top. Right under the bolded text. But here it is https://jsfiddle.net/mdzgwwvd/

Comment: On the JSFiddle you've posted I'm only seeing one postit.

Comment: It is possible to create more using the blue + button for picture postit and the silver button for editable postit note (top right corner). I know the button are overlapping but I'm in the initial stages of this website. Been stuck on the postit problem forever.

Comment: Your JSFiddle is exactly the same as what you want to happen for me. The new postit is totally draggable.

Comment: There are two types of postit. I want the one where I can type text to be draggable. Try the silver button and see if you can drag the new postit note.